# Как искать информацию в официальной документации

Tags: mongoose

Вот есть некий код:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
...
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

в котором есть вызов mongoose.model(...) Я уверенно не могу найти спецификацию этого метода на http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: вся документаця на одной странице - используйте поиск по странице; http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

Comment: @mymedia спасибо. Я уверенно пропускал index.js в меню почему-то. А на одностраничность документа  внимания не обратил.